# Flutter pageview auto-height problem in Listview

Tags: flutter, flutter-pageview

I'm trying to make the pageview be auto height based on its child since the content in child is dynamic. So, the fixed height is not a solution for me.

```
ListView(
  children: [
    Container(
      //height: 300, //i dont want the fixed height
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amber),
      child: PageView(
        children: [
          Text(
            "1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1"), //this would be a dynamic content //this would be a dynamic content
            Text(
            "1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1") //this would be a dynamic content //this would be a dynamic content
        ],
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

**Error Message**
[image: Error Message]

**This is what I'm going to achieve**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the widget with `AspectRatio`.

```dart
ListView(
  children: [
    AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 1 / .4, //width /height
      child: PageView(
        children: [
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but aspectRatio still considers it as fixed height right? since it is not based on its child's height

Comment: On That case, I think you might want need to switch different widget like SingleChildScrolView

Answer (score 0):

Code Exemple:

```
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amber),
          child: SizedBox(
            height: constraints.maxHeight,
            child: PageView(
              children: [
                Text(
                  "1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1",
                ), // This would be dynamic content
                Text(
                  "1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1",
                ), // This would be dynamic content
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  },
);
```

The LayoutBuilder widget is used to get the maximum height of its parent widget, which is the ListView in this case. The SizedBox is then given a height equal to the maximum height of the ListView, ensuring that the PageView can take up the maximum available height without causing an infinite height constraint.

Comment: Got this error "BoxConstraints forces an infinite height." if set the height as double.infinity

Comment: i fixed my answer sorry for this